# UIImageView resizes for in simulator when XIB doesn't

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, autolayout

I have an XIB which looks like this: 
[image], but when I run it in simulator (or on device)
it processes like this:
[image]
and over-streches. How do I prevent it from stretching and being weird when I simulate it? Auto-layout is disabled.

Comment: In attribute inspector for your xib , in simulated metrics have you set the orientation to landscape ?

Comment: @ila Yep! Checked as landscape

Comment: Just a try , go to the size inspector of each of those buttons and disable the springs (the two way arrows in the middle). For the struts  just keep the top and left strut , disable the rest. This will ensure that the buttons are not resized . Also When I look closely the background image is going out of the screen from the right side which means there is something not correct - either the width of the background view is more than 480 fr iphone4.May be u r using an iPhone5 size xib and running on iphone4 size simulator. Make sure right and left strut and horizontal spring is enabled fr view.

Comment: Wow - I had it set to 4Inch, aka iPhone 5. My bad. Submit it as a answer so I can accept it?

Comment: good you found it. Sure i ll add answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a try , go to the size inspector of each of those buttons and disable the springs (the two way arrows in the middle). For the struts just keep the top and left strut , disable the rest. This will ensure that the buttons are not resized . Also When I look closely the background image is going out of the screen from the right side which means there is something not correct - either the width of the background view is more than 480 fr iphone4.May be u r using an iPhone5 size xib and running on iphone4 size simulator. Make sure right and left strut and horizontal spring is enabled fr view.